# Real-Time Launch Statistics for the Demo-2 Mission

Tags: spacex, launch, engines, statistics

Is it possible to view the statistics such as pounds thrust and pressure of the Dragon Spacecraft's engines in real time. I'm not sure if Space-X or NASA has a part of their website dedicated to this, or if it will only be available after today's launch.